# html5 form not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, submit

I have a search form on every page of my website which works perfectly, when submitting the form it goes to a page called search.php..

I have the same form also on my contact page where i also have a contact form. 
the contact form does not have a submit button because i use ajax to send the post variables to a contact_process.php page. The contact form is working perfectly however on this page the search form does not work.. When I press the submit button on the search form it just refreshes the whole contact page instead of going to the search.php page. can anyone help? thanks.

The javascript and ajax for contact form:

```
document.getElementById('submit_message').addEventListener('click', sendMessage, false);

function sendMessage(){
    $('#submit_message').removeClass("point_finger_animation");
    $('#pointing_finger').fadeOut();
    xmlhttp = createXHR();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    var not_valid_email = false;
    var your_name = document.getElementById("your_name").value;
    var captcha_code = document.getElementById("captcha_code").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var mobile_number = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    if(mobile_number.length < 10 || mobile_number.length > 14){
        var not_valid_mobile = true;
    }
    var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length){
        var not_valid_email = true;
    }

    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "contact_process.php" ,true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if((your_name == "" || your_name == null) || (not_valid_mobile) || (not_valid_email) || (message == "" || message == null)){
        $('#container_wrapper').scrollTop(0);
        document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = "<p>Message not sent!</p>";
        if(your_name == "" || your_name == null){
            document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = "<p>Oops! You forgot to fill in a required field!</p>";
        }else if(not_valid_email){
            document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = "<p>The email address you entered is invalid!</p>";
        }else if(not_valid_mobile){
            document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = "<p>The mobile number you entered is invalid!</p>";

        }else if(message == "" || message == null){
            document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = "<p>Oops! You forgot to fill in a required field!</p>";
        }

    }else{
        xmlhttp.send("your_name=" + your_name + "&email=" + email + "&mobile=" + mobile_number + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message + "&captcha_code=" + captcha_code);

    }
}

function callback(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        refreshCaptcha();
        document.getElementById("form_results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        $('#container_wrapper').scrollTop(0);
    }
}
```

html for contact form

```
<section id="form_area" class="content_box">
                <div id="form_results"></div>
                <form id ="contact_form" method="post" action="">
                        <label>Your Name (required)</label>
                        <input id="your_name" name="your_name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" onfocus = "checkEnter()">

                        <label>Your Email (required)</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus = "checkEnter()">

                    <label>Mobile Number (required)</label>
                        <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" onfocus = "checkEnter()">

                    <label>Subject</label>
                        <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject (Optional)" onfocus = "checkEnter()" >

                        <label>Your Message (required)</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" type="text" placeholder="Please leave your message here" onfocus = "checkEnter()"></textarea>

                    <label>Please enter the Captcha below (required). Letters are not case sensitive.</label>
                    <div id="captcha_wrapper">
                        <img id="captcha" src="/finalne2/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
                        <span id="captcha_refresh"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="captcha_code" type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" onfocus = "checkEnter()" onblur = "checkFields()"/>

                    <div id="submit_area">
                        <div id="submit_message" class="menu_level_1 button_style">Send</div>
                        <div id="pointing_finger"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i></div>
                    </div
                </form><!--End of contact_form-->
            </section><!--End of form_area-->
```

html for search form:

```
<div id="search_wrapper" class="menu_level_1">
        <div id="search_box">
                <form action="search.php" method="get">

                    <input id="search_content" placeholder="Search website" type="text" name="query" size="40" value="" action="" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500">  
                    <button id="submit_search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>      
                    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Update:
@Malk thanks for spotting the missing bracket in the closing div of the contact form :) that was indeed the problem :)

Comment: Sounds like an HTML error. Is this copy/pasted directly? Notice the `</div` (without the closing >) before the `</form><!--End of contact_form-->` line.

Comment: oh wow.. I never noticed that and that indeed was the problem.. I guess because my contact form always worked i didn't think to check that.. you have saved me hours of trying to solve it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but maybe try specifying an explicit action attribute in the contact form.

```
<form id ="contact_form" method="post" action="some_page_here">
```

Comment: Thanks but because I was using ajax to send the contact form i didn't need an action attribute. It turned out I was missing a closing bracket on the div in the contact form.. thanks for your help :)